# How do you solve a question like

Tags: functions, polynomials, pattern-matching

Suppose that a, b, and c are real numbers, and $P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. If $P(x + 2) + P(x + 1) − P(x) = 2x^2 + 15x + 20$, what is the value of $P(10)$?

This is a grade 8 Canadian Math Challenger's question (Regional, 2014 Round 1, Q24). Students get about 90 seconds to solve each question in this round. I tried different values of X but it seems that there has to be a trick to solve something like this in 90 or so seconds. This question can be found on page #525 of this PDF egbc.ca/getmedia/5cfa019a-f50b-4a12-97b0-e8ebf020ce71/

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Sub the form of $P(x)$ in the given equation and compare coefficients: you get 3 equations in $a,b,c$ which you can solve to figure out $P(x)$

Comment: Hello @APCorreia: This is a grade 8 Canadian Math Challenger's question (Regional, 2014 Round 1, Q24). Students get about 90 seconds to solve each question in this round. I tried different values of X but it seems that there has to be a trick to solve something like this in 90 or so seconds. This question can be found on page #525 of this PDF https://www.egbc.ca/getmedia/5cfa019a-f50b-4a12-97b0-e8ebf020ce71/Quest-Archive.pdf.aspx

Comment: As @PrasunBiswas has pointed out, you can expand each expression, sum them up and compare the coefficients. There is already an answer to this question. If you still have any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$
$$P(x+1) = a(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + c=ax^2+(2a+b)x+(a+b+c)$$
$$P(x+2) = a(x+2)^2 + b(x+2) + c=ax^2+(4a+b)x+(4a+2b+c)$$
$$P(x+2)+P(x+1)-P(x)=ax^2+(6a+b)x+(5a+3b+c)=2x^2 +15x+20$$

Thus, comparing coefficients, we see that:
$$a=2$$
$$12+b=15; b=3$$
$$10+9+c=20; c=1$$

Thus, $P(x)=2x^2+3x+1$

$P(10)=231$

Answer (score 1):

Plugging numbers which have a P(0) somewhere in the equation may help you go a little faster to get your linear equations. Like so:

Plugging in $x=-1$:

$$2b+c = 7$$

Plugging in $x=0$:

$$5a+3b+c=20$$

Plugging in $x=-2$:

$$ -3a + b +c = -2$$

a=2, b=3, c=1

Then $P(10) = 231.$